# Does Cassandra block writes while flushing memtable?

Tags: cassandra

For a given partition, will Cassandra block writes while flushing memtable contents to disk? If it does not block, then how does it achieve a non-blocking solution?

Comment: A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think Cassandra might create a new memtable for writes while it is flushing the old one. But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Cassandra does not create a new memtable -- it just recycles the segment(s) once it has been flushed to disk. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Writes do not get blocked at all in Cassandra because mutations do not get persisted to existing data files as it does for traditional relational databases.

Mutations from write requests are stored in memory structures called memtables and are *appended* to end of commitlogs for durability. The key here is that the mutations are *added* to the end of the commitlogs so there is no disk seek required therefore making writes very, very fast. Cheers!